# Align two input groups with different widths next to each other

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align 2 input groups, one with span 8 & other with 4 next to each other. I used form inline but it doesn't take the intended width.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <div class="input-group"> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-8" placeholder="Username">
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <div class="input-group"> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-4" placeholder="Ref No.">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around i found this solution:

HTML

```
<div class="row form-input">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ref no.">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-input">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Monthly Rent">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Deposit">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-input, .form-input input{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following css

```
.form-group{
        float:left;
    }
```